# Error in loading images in heroku server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a ruby on rails application where I use some images in a javascript file, like this:

```
  var urlshapes = "/assets/shapes/";

    // image loader
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "isit.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "ec.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "bc.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "bb.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "io.png");
  loadAllImages();
```

Using the WEBrick server it works, but when I upload to the heroku server I get this errors:

[image]

I have read this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline, and in result I added this line `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` in my Gem file, but I still get the errors.

What should I do?

Rails version: 4.1.5  Ruby version: 2.1.2

Comment: Did you try to reach these assets manually on another directory? Like http://<your_app>.herokuapp.com/shapes/bc.png and so on?

Personally I recommend putting these files into `public` directory

Comment: If I tried manually I get this "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.". My question is why?
I'm going to try it in the public folder. What should be the url in the public folder?

Comment: Just http://<your_app>.herokuapp.com/ . Check first answer from Suomi. It may be a good place to start.

Comment: I put everything in the public folder and now it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). This means assets have different paths between development and production. You need to use the [image path helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path) to get the correct path/URL on every environment. The image_path helper is probably what you need. The problem is this is a Ruby method and you want to call it in Javascript code. There are 2 solutions:

- Append .erb at the end of your javascript filename. You can then use ERB like you do in the views. e.g. `imageURLs.push("<%= image_path('isit.png') %>")`
- If your Javascript code is loaded from an HTML page, add the array of the image URLs inside your views, then reference them via Javascript. You can either add a data attribute to an HTML element, or simply add a `<script>` tag. e.g.:

`<div data-images="['<%= image_path('1.png') %>', '<%= image_path('2.png') ']">`

or

`<%= javascript_tag("images = ['#{image_path("1.png")}']") %>`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In the config/environments/production.rb, did you change this to true, as so:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Heroku pre-compiles the assets into public/assets, so you need to change the config settings.

Comment: In this link  it says that including the gem 'rails_12factor' does the same.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I put everything in the public folder and changed to this:

```
  var urlshapes = "/shapes/";

    // image loader
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "isit.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "ec.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "bc.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "bb.png");
  imageURLs.push(urlshapes + "io.png");
  loadAllImages();
```